# Game stops reacting after 15th click when 15 balls generated

Tags: python, pygame

This game will generate a ball in a random location on the grid after each click.

[image: grid after 15 clicks with 15 balls]

#### Issue

But it stops reacting on further clicks after reaching 15 balls (see screenshot above).

#### Pygame Code

```py
import pygame
from random import randint

pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((915,915))
colors = [(102,51,0),(0,255,255),(0,255,0),(0,51,204),(102,0,204),(255,255,0),(255,0,0)]
slots = []
x = 0
y = 0
click_pos = (0,0)
play = True
#Size of squares
size = 83
white = (255,255,255)
gray = (200,200,200)
deep_gray = (20,20,20)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
boardLength = 9
z = 0
clicked = False
selecting = False
ball_spawn = False
balls_x = []
balls_y = []
ball_amount = 0
ball_color = []
ball_drew = 0
get_ball_pos = False
click_once = 0
#bg color
gameDisplay.fill(deep_gray)

# GRID
while boardLength > z:
    #border
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [size-5,size-5,boardLength*size+5 ,boardLength*size+5])
    #grid squares
    for i in range(1,boardLength+1):
        for z in range(1,boardLength+1):
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, gray, [size*z,size*i,size-5,size-5])

# GAME
while play == True:
    for events in pygame.event.get():
        if events.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            click_pos = list(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            clicked = True
        if events.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False
    #get click pos on grid
    if clicked == True:
        click_once += 1
        if click_once == 1:
            x = round((click_pos[0]-size/2) / size)
            y = round((click_pos[1]-size/2) / size)
            if x > 0 and x < 10 and y > 0 and y < 10:
                grid_x = x*size
                grid_y = y*size
            clicked = False
            selecting = True
            get_ball_pos = True
            ball_spawn = True
    else:
        click_once = 0
    #selector
    if selecting:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, green, (grid_x,grid_y,size-5,size-5), 5)

    # BALLS
    while ball_spawn:
        while get_ball_pos:
            ball_grid_x = randint(1,9)
            ball_grid_y = randint(1,9)
            if not (ball_grid_x in balls_x and ball_grid_y in balls_y):
                get_ball_pos = False
                balls_x.append(ball_grid_x)
                balls_y.append(ball_grid_y)
                ball_color.append(colors[randint(0,6)])
                ball_amount += 1
        while ball_drew < ball_amount:
            pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, ball_color[ball_drew], (balls_x[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2, balls_y[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25)
            pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, (balls_x[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2, balls_y[ball_drew]*size + size*0.5 - 2), 25, 5)
            ball_drew += 1
        ball_drew = 0
        ball_spawn = False
    #final result
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

#### Stacktrace after interrupting

Since the program does not react on clicks anymore I interrupted it in console  with CTRL + C. After interrupting execution the console shows following:

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.6.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO_pygame.py", line 73, in <module>
    ball_grid_x = randint(1,9)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 192, in randrange
    istop = _int(stop)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Simply saying "it crashes" is too vague. What exactly happens?

Comment: Instead of saying it "it crashes" you could describe what was expected but does not happen (no reaction on further clicks), give a screenshot or console dump. I updated your question with my observations of the runtime-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the condition:

> ```py
> if not (ball_grid_x in balls_x and ball_grid_y in balls_y):
> ```

This condition checks whether there is a ball in line `ball_grid_x` and whether there is a ball in column `ball_grid_y`. However, these can be different balls. Therefore, if there is a ball in every row and a ball in every column, this condition creates an infinite loop:

You need to test if there is a ball at positionv  `(ball_grid_x, ball_grid_y)`:

```py
if not (ball_grid_x, ball_grid_y) in zip(balls_x, balls_y):
```